# run gpg encryption command through cronjob

Tags: linux, shell, cron, gnupg

I have a script which executes the gpg encryption command in a sh script throught cronjob.
This is a part of my script

```
do
gpg --batch --no-tty --yes --recipient $Key  --output $Outputdir/${v}.pgp --encrypt  ${v}
echo "$?"
if  ["$?" -eq 0 ];
then 
mv $Inputdir/${v} $Readydir/
echo "file moved"
else
echo "error in encryption"
fi
done
```

the echo $? gives value as 2.

tried the bellow command also

```
gpg --batch --home-dir dir --recipient $Key  --output $Outputdir/${v}.pgp --encrypt  ${v}
```

where dir=/usr/bin/gpg

---

My complete script

```
  #set -x
  PT=/gonm1_apps/xfb/ref/phoenix_drop
  Inputdir=`grep Inputdir  ${PT}/param.cfg | cut -d "=" -f2`
  Outputdir=`grep Outputdir ${PT}/param.cfg | cut -d "=" -f2`
  Key=`grep Key ${PT}/param.cfg | cut -d "=" -f2`
  Readydir=`grep Readydir ${PT}/param.cfg | cut -d "=" -f2`
  echo $USER
  if [ "$(ls -la $Inputdir | grep -E 'S*.DAT')" ]; then
   echo "Take action $Inputdir is not Empty"
   cd $Inputdir
 for v in `ls SID_090_*`
 do
  gpg --recipient $Key  --output $Outputdir/${v}.pgp --encrypt  ${v}
          echo "$?"
 if  ["$?" -eq 0 ];
 then
  mv $Inputdir/${v} $Readydir/
          echo "file moved"
  else
          echo "error in encryption"
 fi
 done
cd ${PT}
else
echo "$Inputdir is Empty"
fi
```

Comment: You should get an error message printed. If you're discarding the output anywhere (`2>/dev/null` or similar), remove that. Are you executing the cronjob using the same user you've tested the script manually?

Comment: Yes I have executed the cron with same user, I tried a new java code to do the same and got the error message as public key not found.

Comment: Are you _really sure_ running the cron job under the same user? What happens if you run `echo $USER`? It looks like GnuPG is trying to lookup the key in another user's GnuPG home directory. `--home-dir dir` will use some `dir` subfolder in the user's home directory, better give an absolute path. Also remember to take care of permissions if using `--homedir`.

Comment: And what about the previous command where i have not mentioned the ---homedir.Is there something wrong in it?

Comment: Please post a minimal, but complete example script reproducing the error and the exact crontab line used for executing the script, and include `echo $USER` in the script. Add the exact output to the question. The information you give is much too blurry, answering is just guesswork right now. Usually, problems with GnuPG under cron are all because of permissions or wrong GnuPG home directories.

Comment: the echo $USER prints as root when executed on cronjob and as my username when executed manually.

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG manages individual keyrings and "GnuPG home directories" per user. A commmon problem when calling GnuPG from web services or cronjobs is executing them as another user.

This means that the other user's GnuPG does look up keys in the wrong key ring (home directory), and if that's fixed it should not have access permissions to the GnuPG home directory at all (not an issue when running a cron or web server as root, but that shouldn't be done for pretty much this reason first hand).

There are different ways to mitigate the issue:

- **Run the web server or cron job under another user.** This might be a viable solution for cron jobs, but very likely not for web services. `sudo` or `su` might help at running GnuPG as another user.
- **Import the required (private/public) keys to the other user's GnuPG home directory**, for example by switching to the `www-data` or `root` user (or whatever it's called on your machine).
- **Change GnuPG's behavior to use *another user's* home directory.** You can do so with `--home-dir /home/[username]/.gnupg` or shorter `--home-dir ~username/.gnupg` if your shell resolves the short-hand. Better don't do this, as GnuPG is very strict at verifying access privileges and refuse to work if those are too relaxed. GnuPG doesn't like permissions allowing other users but the owner to access a GnuPG home directory at all, for good reasons.
- **Change GnuPG's behavior to use *a completely unrelated folder* as home directory**, for example somewhere your application is storing data anyway. Usually, the best solution. Make sure to set the owner and access permissions appropriately. An example would be the option `--home-dir /var/lib/foo-product/gnupg`.

Comment: can we export our public key to all the user on a server??

Comment: Sure -- just go through all of them, just requires a few lines of scripting. But _the necessity of doing so_ does not feel like a robust solution. Do you need to run it from multiple users? If so, better store the key on your hard disk and `gpg --import` it before using (reimporting does not break anything if the key already exists).

Answer (score 0):

if

> ```
>        the echo $USER prints as root when executed on cronjob and as 
>        username when executed manually
> ```

Then you need to login as the user and use a command such as "crontab -e" to add a cronjob for that user to run your script

Comment: If we dont have the privilages to add the crontab through our user then??

Comment: You apparently have privilleges to add a root crontab so I am surprised that you are not able to add a crontab for your user.  If you really cannot do it ask your systems administrator

Comment: can we export our public key to all the users on a server box??